# Finding an angle inside an irregular quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, fractions, quadrilateral

I’ve been trying to solve this question for several days now and I still got no clue on how to solve it.

> Find $x$ [image]

Comment: @KhunpolJermisiri Welcome to Math SE! It would be good to search, and research in depth for an answer to your question, and show your steps as to what you have tried. Can you also please correct your title - your diagram appears to be a trapezoid. If you do those things, I will give you **an upvote**.

Comment: Hint: the angles in a triangle add to $180^\circ$ and the angles around the center point all add to $360^\circ$.

Comment: @TobyMak they don't seem to be parallel from the given angles: $13 \neq 34$

Comment: @NickPavlov You're right - the angles don't match up, and the diagram is drawn really inaccurately.

Comment: @Toby Mak What is your trying?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I'm not going to even put in the effort if the OP doesn't either. If they're too lazy to even try, why should I care?

Comment: @Toby Mak I think it's very bad if in the math forum you not going to even put in the effort for the problem solving. Very bad.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg What I said was a bit harsh - but here's what I believe:  you don't *have* to answer every question if you don't want to. I think that much as we might want to help, we just have to let some questions pass, and that is quite different from being lazy. If I already believe this, I don't think it would be easy to change my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $AC\cap BD=\{E\}$.

Thus, $$\frac{\sin(103^{\circ}-x)}{\sin{x}}=\frac{ED}{EC}=\frac{ED}{AE}\cdot\frac{AE}{BE}\cdot\frac{BE}{EC}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin64^{\circ}}{\sin13^{\circ}}\cdot\frac{\sin17^{\circ}}{\sin86^{\circ}}\cdot\frac{\sin43^{\circ}}{\sin34^{\circ}}.$$
I got $x=39^{\circ}$.

I got it by the following way.

We have
$$\sin103^{\circ}\cot{x}-\cos103^{\circ}=\frac{\cos26^{\circ}}{4\sin13^{\circ}\cos43^{\circ}\cos17^{\circ}}$$ or
$$\cot{x}=\frac{\cos26^{\circ}}{2\sin26^{\circ}\cos43^{\circ}\cos17^{\circ}}-\tan13^{\circ}.$$
But
$$\frac{\cos26^{\circ}}{2\sin26^{\circ}\cos43^{\circ}\cos17^{\circ}}-\tan13^{\circ}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\tan26^{\circ}(\cos60^{\circ}+\cos26^{\circ})}-\tan13^{\circ}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\frac{2\tan13^{\circ}}{1-\tan^213^{\circ}}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-\tan^213^{\circ}}{1+\tan^213^{\circ}}\right)}-\tan13^{\circ}=$$
$$=\frac{1-\tan^413^{\circ}}{\tan13^{\circ}(3-\tan^213^{\circ})}-\tan13^{\circ}=\frac{1-3\tan^213^{\circ}}{3\tan13^{\circ}-\tan^313^{\circ}}=\cot39^{\circ},$$
which says $x=39^{\circ}.$

Comment: Why is(are) there downvote(s) on this answer?

Comment: @BAI I think that some people, including myself, find it strange that people put all their time and effort on a question that the OP may not even care about. Again, opinions vary from person to person, so there might be someone who downvoted for this reason.

Comment: The answer is correct .thank  you ! But I’m wondering if there’s any solution that doesn’t involve trigonometry?

Comment: @KhunpolJermsiri From the angles in your diagram, $BC$ is not parallel to $AD$ since $34º ≠ 13º$. Since we have found the shape to be an irregular quadrilateral, there's not much we can do other than use trigonometry, because we can't get an idea of what the shape looks like.

Comment: @TobyMak yeah right, my english is a bit bad ,I’m sorry ,I’ll fix it.

Comment: @TobyMak I got the question from the exam that didn’t have a diagram of the Quadilateral and we havent learn any trigonometry that involve weird angles too. So there must be other solution right.?

Comment: @KhunpolJermsiri Yes, there is another solution. If the answer is 39 (exactly), that's not random. Neither are all the other numbers in the problem, with numerous interesting connections between them.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: "I got $x=39^{\circ}$.". Your posted solution should provide the justification for that claim. Did you _prove_ it? If not (e.g., if you solved _numerically_), that should be disclosed in your answer.

Comment: @quasi I proved it by trigonometric identities. If you wish I am ready to show.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Absolutely, please show it. The answer is hugely incomplete without that justification.

Comment: @quasi I added something. See now.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Thanks. That was a needed, nontrivial part of the solution (+1).

Comment: @quasi You are welcome! Good luck!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: You have a typo in the first line of the new edit.

Comment: @quasi I fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the construction I did with GeoGebra. The auxiliary circle is needed to construct the angle of $13°$ in $D$

$$
.
$$

[image]

Comment: I can see how you get $26^\circ$ and $77^\circ$, but how do you find any of the rest ($64^\circ$ and $39^\circ$)?

Comment: With GeoGebra https://www.geogebra.org/

Comment: Nice picture! But it's not solution of course.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I was waiting for the Angel Of Death aka Michael Rozenberg :)

Comment: @Raffaele Anyone can be appointed to this post, but not me. :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg The OP wrote "Find $x$" I could have answered "IT'S HERE!" drawing an arrow on his/her drawing :)  Anyway you are one of the best. I am just an *amateur*...  and I bet I could be your GrandPa